# cov(meager) strictly between $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

Is is consistent that $\aleph_1 < \text{cov(meager)} < 2^{\aleph_0}$?

I can only seem to find references for results that assert it is consistent that it (or other cardinal characteristics) is $\aleph_1$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$.

If this is possible could someone provide a reference or sketch the argument. Thanks.

Comment: This is far from my comfort zone. But perhaps iterating $\aleph_2$ Cohen reals with $\aleph_3$ Random reals will work?

Comment: Why not looking at Chapter 7 of Tomek Bartoszyński and Haim Judah, *Set theory. On the structure of the real line*. A K Peters, Ltd., Wellesley, MA, 1995?

Comment: @TomekKania Do you know where this is in chapter 7? After a quick look it appears that the only consistency result there involve assigning to each cardinal characteristic $\aleph_1$ or $\aleph_2 = 2^{\aleph_0}$ in a way that obeys the cichon diagram.

Comment: I think the ideas from Bartoszynski and Judah should lead to a proof.  If you want another reference to look at, Blass's chapter of the Handbook of Set Theory should tell you all you need to know.  (And I think it's freely available on his webpage.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with a model where continuum is large, say $\omega_5$. Then do a finite support iteration of random forcing of length $\omega_2$. This is ccc so continuum is at least $\omega_5$. The Cohen reals appearing at stages of cofinality $\omega$ will ensure that $\omega_1$ meager sets cannot cover all reals and the $\omega_2$-many meager sets coded by the random reals will cover all reals.

An interesting fact about covering numbers: While Arnie Miller has shown that the cofinality of covering of the meager ideal is always uncountable, a famous result of Shelah is that the covering of the null ideal could be $\omega_{\omega}$.

Comment: Just because I think you'll probably be able to give a quick answer, is my suggestion to start with a model of $\sf CH$ then add $\omega_2$ Cohen reals, followed by $\omega_3$ Random reals going to work?

Comment: The translations of a conull meager set by any $\omega_1$ many random reals cover R so covering of meager ideal is $\omega_1$. This also shows that cov(Meager) is at most non(Null) since the sum of a conull meager set and a non null set is all of R.